# How to plot the predicted probabilities of my model?

Tags: r

I've been struggling a bit with the following code, I just get the following error code when trying to create my model:

> Error in eval_tidy(dot, data = mask) : object 'age' not found.

The data I'm using is from the `socviz` package:

```
GeneralSocialSurvey2016 <- gss_sm %>%
  mutate(Education = as.factor(case_when(degree == "Graduate" ~ "1",
                                         degree == "Bachelor" ~ "1",
                                         degree != "Graduate" ~ "0",
                                         degree != "Bachelor" ~ "0",
                                         degree == NA ~ "NA",
                                         degree != NA ~ "0")))
```

Here I'm trying to estimate my data and adding standard errors for plotting later on. And it's here I keep running into that error message. How can I go about fixing this, and why does it even show up?

```
ModelD <- augment(glm(obama ~ age + religion,
                      data = GeneralSocialSurvey2016,
                      family = "binomial"
                      (link = "logit")),
          type.predict = "response",
          se_fit = TRUE,
          newdata = expand_grid(age,
                                religion = as_factor(c("Protestant", 
                                                       "Catholic", 
                                                       "None"))))
```

And then the plot:

```
ModelD %>%
      mutate(lower = .fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
             upper = .fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = age, 
                   y = .fitted,
                   color = religion,
                   fill = religion)) + 
      geom_line() +
      scale_color_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 3,
                                              name = "Darjeeling1")) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 3,
                                             name = "Darjeeling1"))+
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower,
                      ymax = upper), 
                  alpha = 0.2) +
      theme_bw()
```

Thank you kindly for any help solving this!

Comment: As qdread points out the issue is simply with the `expand_grid()` call, nothing to do with plotting. At the top of the post, the feature engineering you do on `education` is not necessary for this question, but FYI it seems like you're using `case_when()` incorrectly. If you have multiple conditions you can use things like `%in%` or combine with logical and (`&`)/or (`|`) operators.

Comment: @DanAdams Agreed. I did not want to get into that in the answer. Another thing to note is that you should use `is.na(degree)` instead of `degree == NA`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `augment` call, the `newdata` argument expects a data frame with new combinations of predictor variables that you want to generate model predictions for. This isn't automatically taken from your input data, you are creating it manually. So in your call to `expand_grid()`, it does not pull the `age` column automatically from anywhere. You need to explicitly specify it.

For example you could get the fitted values of probability of supporting Obama for all combinations of religion and ages in your dataset at increments of 1 year. First get the range of ages in your dataset (the youngest respondent was 18 and the oldest 89) then pass a sequence of ages to the `expand_grid()` function. You will get a fitted value for all combinations of age and religion.

```
ages <- range(GeneralSocialSurvey2016$age, na.rm = TRUE)

ModelD <- augment(glm(obama ~ age + religion,
                      data = GeneralSocialSurvey2016,
                      family = "binomial"
                      (link = "logit")),
                  type.predict = "response",
                  se_fit = TRUE,
                  newdata = expand_grid(age = seq(ages[1], ages[2]),
                                        religion = as_factor(c("Protestant", 
                                                               "Catholic", 
                                                               "None"))))
```

The `ModelD` object generated in this way should work with your plotting code.